# OleDBException was unhandled NO value given for one or more parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I am trying to Update a table in an access database from C#.

It is a .mdb type database.

here is the connection string I am using.
      `public MainWindow() {`

```
InitializeComponent();

OleDbConnection cn= new OleDbConnection();}
cn.ConnectionString=@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" 
    + "C:\Users\Angela\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Havnefoged11.mdb;" 
    + "User Id=;Password=;";

cn.Open();

Application.Current.Properties["DBConnection"] = cn;
```

The file is in the correct folder C:\Users\Angela\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

 OleDbConnection conn =             

 (OleDbConnection)Application.Current.Properties["DBConnection"];
 //Below are the values i want to put into the database 
 String dybde = Dybde.Text;
 String bredde = Bredde.Text;
 String plads = PladsNummer.Text;

String StrSQL = 
    "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES (´´"+ plads
        + "´,´" 
        + bredde
        + "´," 
        + dybde+");";

  OleDbCommand InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(StrSQL, conn);

   InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I then get the error 
OleDBException was unhandled NO value given for one or more parameters

I have gone in and changed all the fields in the database to be text
I have checked the field names they are correct.
The ldb file comes when I initialise the program.
but as soon as I press the button I get the error.

Any ideas?

Ps 
I have included the

```
  using System.Data;
   using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Comment: Please format your code in a readable way..!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: David - please read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection

Comment: What is the value of dybde?  I'd bet it's an empty string, or null.  Also, you have an extra single quotejust before your first value.  Finally, it's horrible practice to build SQL strings by contencating in user input.  You open yourself up to SQL Injection.  You should be using Parameterized Queries instead.  (Tons of info if you google "Parameterized Queries .NET")

Comment: SQL Injection: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Hard to tell what's right or wrong without more detail like what are the datatypes of the columns in the database.  The syntax correctness of your SQL depends on those types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, you are open to SQL injection attacks.  You should use parameters.  The reason it is probably failing is that the content of the strings you are inserting may contain a "?" and "?" is implied as "I am expecting a parameter here" and is what is making it choke.

Try changing to

```
String StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer, Bredde, Dybde ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )";
OleDbCommand InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(StrSQL, conn )
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "yourFirstParm", plads );
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "yourSecondParm", bredde );
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "yourThirdParm", dybde );
```

THEN, execute it, but NOTE:  The parameters must be added in the same sequence as your "?" place-holders.

Also, it may be that your backend DOES support named parameters and not "?" values... if so, you may need to adjust to something like

```
String StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer, Bredde, Dybde ) "
      + "VALUES ( @parmPlads, @parmBredde, @parmDybde )";
OleDbCommand InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(StrSQL, conn )
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmPlads", plads );
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmBredde", bredde );
InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@parmDybde", dybde );
```

Comment: Hi Drapp I have put in what the problem was in a reply to Jason. Cheers

Comment: @DavidDrennan, I think with that, you are still open to SQL-Injection.  All his option is doing is a pre-fancy formatting of a string and putting your values into the places of {0}, {1}, {2} respectively.  If you have a "?" in your content from the values, it will probably still cause problem... or open the sql-injection...  But your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Your `StrSQL` looks a bit suspect. Could you display the value of that string just before you execute it? I'm guessing the apostrophis and/or quotes are getting a bit mixed up.

```
String StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES (´´"+ plads +"´,´"+bredde+"´,"+dybde+");";
```

as a stab in the dark, try this instead:

```
string StrSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')", plads, bredde, dybde);
```

Comment: Hi Jason I have tried that now and got the errorThe INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Plads_nummer'.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again. So iwill check that as well

Comment: I tried what jason said and it did not work but gave me the errorThe INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Plads_nummer'.  I then whent into the file and changed Plads_nummer to pladsnummer(and in the code) this allowed the code to work (I also set up  the apostrophies as suggested. Its weird that i did not get the same error doing it my way as with jasons method as the cause was the same.
Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this:

```
String StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES (´´"+ 
                    plads +"´,´"+bredde+"´,"+dybde+");";
```

I see that you have two apostrophes in front of plads. You probably only need one. If you are having to escape them as double apostrophes, then you would probablyu was doubles before an after each comma.

Comment: @PeterRitchie true... but there's none immediately before dybde either, so I presume it's not a string.

Comment: Hi again, I have tried to mess around with the apostraphies here is how it looks now (the problem remains)                                          String StrSQL = "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES ('"+ plads +"','"+bredde+"','"+dybde+"')"; The apostraphy are inside the quotation marks

Comment: what happens when you try the insert without the concatination (e.g., "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES ('PLADS_NUM','BREDDE', 'Dtybde')" or perhaps "INSERT INTO Bådpladser (Plads_nummer,Bredde,Dybde) VALUES (1234,5678, 9012)" if they are numeric values )

Comment: Hi guys it is sorted now see under Jasons post